# How do you select a random variable within a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have put multiples variables within a function and I was wondering if there was any way possible in JavaScript to select a variable within that function at random. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use an array instead of multiple variables then you can select a random element from the array:

```
function test() {
    var values = ["test","values","go","here"],
        valueToUse = values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];
    // do something with the selected value
    alert(valueToUse);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XDn2f/

(Of course the array doesn't have to contain simple values like the strings I showed, you could have an array of objects, or references to other functions, etc.)

Comment: PS: If the array contains `function`s, remember to add `()` after `valueToUse` if you are executing it right away: `valueToUse()`

Answer (score 1):

If one of your parameters is an array you can randomly select one value from it.

```
function myFunc(arrayInput)
{
     var randomIndex = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
     return (arrayInput[randomIndex]);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `*arrayInput.length` rather than hardcoding `10`? Also, no need to add `1`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have N variables, then it is cleanest to put them in an array and generate a random index into that array.

```
var items = [1,2,3,4];
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
items[index] = whatever;
```

If you only have a couple variables, you can generate a random number and use an `if/else` statement to operate on the desired variable.

```
var a, b;
var index = Math.random();
if (index < 0.5) {
    // operate on a
    a = 3;
} else {
    // operate on b
    b = 3;
}
```